# Cómo generar tests en postman dentro de un for?

Tags: javascript, test, postman

Quiero verificar que todos los users tienen category id igual a 2, siendo category un atributo de la entidad User, hago el siguiente script:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);

for(i=0; i<response._embedded.users.length; i++){
    tests["Loop Tests"] = (response._embedded.users[i]._embedded.category.id === 2);
}
```

pero me sucede que observo: **Test Results(1/1)**
cuando son 10 users, lo cual puedo corroborarlo haciendo:

```
for(i=0; i<response._embedded.users.length; i++){
    console.log(response._embedded.users[i]._embedded.category.id);
}
```

y esto me imprime 10 valores de category id.
Lo que observo es que solo testea la última iteracion, ya que si el último user tiene category.id = 2, entonces obtengo **Test Results (1/1)** pero si le cambio la category al último user obtengo **Test Results (0/1)**

Cómo puedo hacer para obtener algo del tipo **Tests Results(10/10)**?? 
Ya que estoy haciendo 10 tests no uno solo, pero no sé por qué razón no los toma.

Comment: Cuál es tu problema para allu dar te

Comment: intenté describirlo lo mejor posible, qué parte no entendiste?